# How can I give a variable to an action listener?

Tags: java, variables, visibility, actionlistener

I have a static variable `partner` in the class. And I want to set a value of these variable whenever a radio button is pressed. This is the code I tried to use:

```
for (String playerName: players) {
    option = new JRadioButton(playerName, false);
    option.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            partner = playerName;
        }
    });
    partnerSelectionPanel.add(option);
    group.add(option);
}
```

The problem here is that the `actionPerformed` does not see the variable `playerName` created in the loop. How can I pass this variable to the actionListener?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
for (final String playerName: players) {
    option = new JRadioButton(playerName, false);
    option.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            partner = playerName;
        }
    });
    partnerSelectionPanel.add(option);
    group.add(option);
}
```

Local variables passed to inner classes must be final.  Originally I thought that you cannot make `playerName` final in the for loop, but in fact you can. If that wasn't the case, you would simply store `playerName` in additional final variable (`final String pn = playerName`) and used `pn` from `actionPerformed`.

Answer (score 2):

Variable must be **final** to pass it into inner class.

Answer (score 1):

```
JButton button = new JButton("test");

button.addActionListiner(new ActionForButton("test1","test2"));

class ActionForButton implements ActionListener {

    String arg,arg2;
    ActionFroButton(String a,String b) {
        arg = a; arg2 = b;
    }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            Sustem.out.println(arg + "--" + arg2);
        }
}
```